# Instagram API redirect uri

Tags: javascript, api, instagram

I am attempting to get an access token with Instagram's API but I am having trouble, and I believe the issue is because of the redirect URI.

I currently have my redirect uri as: http://socialmediasnapshot.net

However, a user is signing in from http://socialmediasnapshot.net/Instagram.html

I tried entering in the above address as a redirect uri, but it does not work. Is there a way to make it so users can authenticate from an HTML page? I am using the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=' + client_id + '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri + '&response_type=token',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(req) {
        alert('yay')
        alert(JSON.stringify(req))
    },
    error: function(req) {
        alert('boo')
        alert(JSON.stringify(req))
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation,

https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

> Note that the host and path components of your redirect URI must match exactly (including trailing slashes) your registered redirect_uri. You may also include additional query parameters in the supplied redirect_uri, if you need to vary your behavior dynamically

So if you want this to work, I think you would have to change the registered URI as http://socialmediasnapshot.net/Instagram.html

Comment: So I was able to change the redirect uri (I had to hit enter instead of simply "update client"). But now whenever I run it, I recieve the following error: "Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token <". It seems like it is trying to read my the html of my web page? I have searched everywhere and have no idea what to do :\ It also says {readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: Load}, and the error is 'parsererror'

Also to make things even more frustrating, whenever I inspect the element and click on the link it was supposed to go to, it works completely fine and the access_token is generated.

Comment: Also also I tried not using JSONP (because the response doesnt seem to be JSONP), but then I get into the cross-domain issues. To counteract that, I added headers in my ajax request (access-control-allow-origin to '*'), but still nothing worked (I get the error "The request was redirected to...which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight")

Comment: I just tried the link you had posted. 
It is working as far as I can see. 
I think you have already solved the issue. Is it ?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at it completely wrong. I just needed to use window.location.href = (the Ajax URL) to update my page, and grab the token from there!